# Calling static jar function from Unity3D

Tags: android, plugins, jar, static, unity-game-engine

I made and compiled a Android Library, containing a simple class and a simple static function:

```
package moo;

public class MyTestClass {

    public static String Foo(){
        return "Foo from Moo";
    }

}
```

I placed the .jar in my Assets/Plugins/Android Folder. Then In Unity:

```
    void OnGUI () {
        string somestring = "foooooooooooOOooo";

        AndroidJavaClass testClass = new AndroidJavaClass("moo.MyTestClass");
        somestring = testClass.CallStatic<string>("Foo");

        GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 20, 100, 20), somestring);
    }
```

And I get an error:
JNI: Unable to find method id for 'Foo' (static)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject:CallStatic(String, Object[])

Am I missing something to call my static method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 problem as far as I can see:

1. you have to put your jar package to Assets/Plugins/Android/bin;
2. you will always get this error on your windows/mac editor, you have to run this on your android device;

Comment: Just to be clear, even with "Android Build" selected, it won't run in the editor? So I need to build for Android and run on the sim/device?

Comment: No, it won't run even you select android build, you have to run on device to call any jar function.